# How to integrate instagram quick reaction animation?

Tags: android

I want to create animation like instagram quick reaction. Whenever user will click on emoji then the animation should be start.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfaPg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use Lottie Animations for it. They have a vast variety of animation.

Comment: But how would I find which I want.

Comment: you can see their animations